# Debian, apache. Log files eats up all disk space

Tags: apache, apache2, debian

I only have 32 GB disk space on my VPS, and currently the logfiles takes 26 GB. I found the files: access.log.1 and error.log.1, which is 17 gb together (var/log/apache2).

Can I just remove these files to free up some space? 
Is it possible to stop the logging function? I know very litte about servers, and don't understand the logs anyways.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you dont need them, then remove it.
maybe you should install logrotate to delete these files automaticly after some time.
the access and error logs are mostly used for debugging (in my case) or for statistics or because of legal reasons.

You can also disable them: just comment out the lines regarding log in the config for the site (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/*`)

Comment: ok, thanks. And the server won't crash because it can't find the files? Maybe it create a new one?

Comment: nope, it will just create a new one